# Is there any combustion chamber and nozzle cooled with liquid oxygen instead of fuel?

Tags: engines, cooling

There are many rocket engines for liquid propellants which use the fuel (rocket petrol or liquid hydrogen for instance) to cool the walls of the combustion chamber and the nozzle.

But are there any engines which use the oxidizer liquid oxygen for cooling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, DLR tested a EADS/Astrium modified test chamber cooled by liquid oxygen as part of the "Phase 2 Technology Demonstration Programme" research work for Reaction Engines' SABRE engine, some time between 2009 and 2012.

As well as tests using liquid oxygen in the combustion chamber's cooling jacket while running on H2/LOX (shown in CCTV images in the linked document), separate tests at DLR used air in the cooling jacket with heavy hydrogen film cooling in a EADS/Astrium built combustion chamber, while the engine runs on compressed air and hydrogen (shown on the inset image) 
[image: DLR tesing Astrium build oxidiser cooled rocket engine]

Details from [Hempsell, Mark (September 2013)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mark_Hempsell/publication/289579461_Progress_on_SKYLON_and_SABRE/links/5b4f69edaca27217ffa1f647/Progress-on-SKYLON-and-SABRE.pdf). Progress on SKYLON and SABRE (IAC-13.D2.4.6). 64th International Astronautical Congress. Beijing, China.

Comment: And it didn't run on engine-rich mix? :D

Comment: no @SF. it seems these rocket scientists know a thing or two.

Comment: (although that red tinge to the flame suggests *something* other than H and O, but I'm assuming an ablative throat/nozzle)

Comment: So there was liquid oxygen in the cooling jacket and hydrogen film cooling in the combustion chamber but not both during the same test?

Comment: I've reread the summary, @Uwe The LOX test was actually a different test chamber -- as might have been inferred by a closer look at the two test setups.

Comment: @Uwe it says _"The   feasibility   of   cooling   the   rocket   combustion chamber with a combination of air in the cooling jacket and heavy hydrogen film cooling as required during the SABRE’s  air-breathing    mode   was   experimentally tested."_ meaning no, inner hydrogen film cooling was only planned for air breathing mode where air also served as the outer coolant.

Comment: well, @EverydayAstronaut, it doesn't rule out film cooling, but with it being a different chamber the *heavy* film cooling can probably be assumed not to be in place.

Comment: @JCRM I'm also not 100% sure about this, but having searched the referenced paper for the word "film", the passage I cited was the only occurrence.